Association with Composite Primary keys in rails
I was reading the Association with Composite primary keys part on rails docs

I have 3 questions
1- Why are the names of the foreign keys different in the 2 tables shouldn't they be the same for e.g
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = [:first_name, :last_name]
  #original line
  #has_many :books, foreign_key: [:first_name, :last_name]
  has_many :books, foreign_key: [:author_first_name, :author_last_name]
# refers to :author_first_name and :author_last_name in Book table
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, foreign_key: [:author_first_name, :author_last_name]
end

Also since the primary key is specified in the migration table
create_table :orders, primary_key: [:id, :store_id] do |t|
why is it specified again in author.rb
2- The document didn't show anything about creating the migration of books table, is there a way to use t.references or do I just add it manually by creating two columns and making them a composite foreign key?
3- I tried to use similar models
orders (the parent with composite key [ :id, :store_id] )

books(the child with composite foreign  key [:order_id, :order_store_id] )

but i got an error

Passing [:order_id, :order_store_id] array to :foreign_key option on the Book#order association is not supported.
Use the query_constraints: [:order_id, :order_store_id] option instead to represent a composite foreign key.

and it worked with query_constraints instead
I tried copying the exact same code on rails docs

By convention, the foreign key is prefixed with the association name. For a single key it would default to :author_id with "author" being the association.
